# celery daemon using systemd not running

Tags: celery, ubuntu-16.04, systemd

i am using ubuntu 16 and systemd for running celery as a daemon.i have created the unit file also but i am not able to run celery as a service. why is this error?

**/etc/systemd/system/celery.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=Celery Service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=celery
Group=celery
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/celery
WorkingDirectory=/srv/weaver/src
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '${CELERY_BIN} multi start ${CELERYD_NODES} \
  -A ${CELERY_APP} --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE} \
  --logfile=${CELERYD_LOG_FILE} --loglevel=${CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL} ${CELERYD_OPTS}'
ExecStop=/bin/sh -c '${CELERY_BIN} multi stopwait ${CELERYD_NODES} \
  --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE}'
ExecReload=/bin/sh -c '${CELERY_BIN} multi restart ${CELERYD_NODES} \
  -A ${CELERY_APP} --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE} \
  --logfile=${CELERYD_LOG_FILE} --loglevel=${CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL} ${CELERYD_OPTS}'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**file at /etc/default/celery**

```
ENABLED="true"
CELERYD_NODES="worker1"
#CELERYD_NODES="worker1 worker2 worker3"
CELERY_BIN="/usr/local/bin/celery"
CELERY_APP="main:celery_app"
CELERYD_CHDIR="/srv/weaver/src"
CELERYD_OPTS=" --queue=weaver  --time-limit=100000 --concurrency=2"
CELERYD_LOG_FILE="/var/log/celery/%N.log"
CELERYD_PID_FILE="/var/run/celery2/%N.pid"
CELERYD_USER="celery"
CELERYD_GROUP="celery"
CELERY_CREATE_DIRS=1
# Change Celery Beat
CELERYBEAT_CHDIR="/srv/weaver/src"
# Log files
CELERYBEAT_LOG_FILE="/var/log/celery/celerybeat.log"
# Celery Beat Log files
CELERYBEAT_PID_FILE="/var/run/celery/celerybeat.pid"
# Scheduler for celery
CELERYBEAT_OPTS=" --pidfile=/var/run/celery/celerybeat.pid  --sch
```

**OUTPUT OF RUNNING SERVICE**

```
● celery.service - Celery Service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/celery.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2017-01-12 17:12:32 IST; 2min 17s ago
  Process: 18561 ExecStop=/bin/sh -c ${CELERY_BIN} multi stopwait ${CELERYD_NODES}    --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE} (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 18540 ExecStart=/bin/sh -c ${CELERY_BIN} multi start ${CELERYD_NODES}    -A ${CELERY_APP} --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE}    --logfile=${CELERYD_LOG_FIL
 Main PID: 18555 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jan 12 17:12:30 fb01 systemd[1]: Starting Celery Service...
Jan 12 17:12:31 fb01 sh[18540]: celery multi v3.1.23 (Cipater)
Jan 12 17:12:31 fb01 sh[18540]: > Starting nodes...
Jan 12 17:12:31 fb01 sh[18540]:         > worker1@fb01: OK
Jan 12 17:12:31 fb01 systemd[1]: Started Celery Service.
Jan 12 17:12:32 fb01 systemd[1]: celery.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 12 17:12:32 fb01 sh[18561]: celery multi v3.1.23 (Cipater)
Jan 12 17:12:32 fb01 sh[18561]: > worker1@fb01: DOWN
Jan 12 17:12:32 fb01 systemd[1]: celery.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jan 12 17:12:32 fb01 systemd[1]: celery.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: Please also include content of celery log files, path is defined in config file you presented:  `CELERYD_LOG_FILE="/var/log/celery/%N.log"`

Comment: @running.t logs are empty. ubuntu system is not able to run it as a service thats why the errror

Comment: Then I am not sure if anyone is able to help you. The only info you showed is that celery is exiting with exit code 1. You will have to debug it somehow. Maybe some info in syslog or in /var/log/messages? BTW this question **should** be asked on different service e.g. http://askubuntu.com or http://superuser.com,  as is is not related to programming.

Comment: i can see in above log `Main PID: 18555 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)` can this be error regarding PID file ??

Comment: An Exit code of 1 simply means there was an error. You need more logging from Celery to understand why it crashed. Your issue appears to be with your Celery configuration and not your systemd configuration.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not involve tools used primarily for programming. https://askubuntu.com/questions/871035/how-can-i-get-the-celery-daemon-to-run-on-ubuntu-16-04-using-systemd seems to be the same question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because From the tag: systemd questions should be for *programming questions* using systemd or its libraries. Questions about *configuring the daemon* (including writing unit files) are better directed to Unix & Linux: https://unix.stackexchange.com. Please delete this.

Answer (score 0):

I just hit this exact issue.  My problem was a configuration issue.  In particular, I wasn't setting 
CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL
in my environment file. (/etc/default/celeryd in your case).  It looks like you have made the same mistake.

(I also had a few other configuration issues that I needed to resolve.  I discovered these by running celery on the commandline.)

Answer (score 0):

I had this same symptom, turned out to be permissions.

In my case something like:

```
chmod o+x /srv/weaver/src
```

sorted it.

Note: That this is **not** the best way to enable the required permission but that's not pertinent to this answer.